# correct path for image tag

Tags: reactjs, image, path, src

[image]Good evening,

i wanted to ask, what is the rule when you create paths for image tags or modules?
I have in VScode inside the public folder and pictures folder. I want to get the picture to my about.js file which is in the src folder. My question is what is the path. And what is the rule?

I put an image down so that you can see where i am currently.

```
[![image of vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNUel.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNUel.png)
```

i tried to add two dots like this ../puplic/pictures....... and than i tried it with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One dot = "current directory"
Two dots = "Up one level"

So when you're giving the path "../public/*" you're telling your script to:

- Go to the parent directory
- Search for public/*

What it looks like from your screenshot is that you should give the following path:

../pictures/X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `public` folder to upload the images, then you can simply use:

```
<img src="/pictures/logo.svg" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Notice that you can omit the `public` and `.` from the url